# Reputation points from Silver Yearling Badge

Tags: support, reputation, badges

Why have the +200 reputation points for my Silver Yearling Badge not been added to my `superuser` account, but they have been added to all my other linked accounts?

**Edit:** After checking more carefully, I've noticed that the +200 reputation only applied to some of my accounts. How is this determined?

Comment: Yep, we're giving out free rep and additional privileges based on who's been registered the longest.

Comment: darn. I've been ripped off for my 400 rep for two silver badges ;p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, let me explain:

- You don't get +200 rep when you're awarded a Yearling badge
- Yearling badge is awarded if you earn 200 rep in the last calendar year
- You get a +100 rep bonus if you have atleast one account on the network with rep > 200.

Your reputation graph says you've been awarded the bonus. SO I'm not sure what exactly that you're expecting..

Comment: Thanks. I was confused, but I understand now :)